# Screen does not update after SignIn in flutter/firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, updating

I'm new to Flutter & Firebase, and i'm currently stuck in a problem where i can't update the screen (from Sign in Screen to Home Screen) after signing in using email & password, where i have to restart the application in order to see the update. let's not forget that Sign out work perfectly fine.

For my example, the user has to choose first wether he is a client or a service provider through the 'ChooseBox Screen', then he will proceed to the sign in Screen that belongs to the chosen option.

Scenario: :MyApp => Wrapper => chooseBox Screen => Sign in Screen => Home Screen

Note: the sign in works perfectly fine and update to the Home Screen when i remove the chooseBox where the scenario becomes this:

Scenario 2: MyApp => Wrapper => Sign in Screen => Home Screen
main.dart

```
import 'package:RemedyBox/Services/authentication.dart';
import 'package:RemedyBox/generatedRoutes.dart';
import 'package:RemedyBox/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthService>(
          create: (_) => AuthService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
            create: (context) => context.read<AuthService>().authStateChange),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrapper.dart

```
import 'package:RemedyBox/Screens/Authentications/chooseBox.dart';
import 'package:RemedyBox/SignPage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Screens/Home/homeFile.dart';

class wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = context.watch<User>();

    if (user == null) {
      return chooseBox();
    }
    return homeScreen();
  }
}
```

ChooseBox.dart, this is the widget where i use to push the chooseBox to the sign in Screen

```
child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/SignIn');
                      },
```

SignIn.dart

```
import 'package:RemedyBox/Services/authentication.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: MediaQuery.of(context).padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<AuthService>().SignIn(
                      email: emailController.text.trim(),
                      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                    );
              },
              child: Text("Sign in"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, that the Sign in page was not part of the wrapper tree, and showing the Home page after the sign in can't be done cause the sign in page was still present. The solution was to push replacement towards the root so it can update the status and show the home page.

SignIn.dart

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await context.read<AuthService>().SignIn(
                      email: emailController.text.trim(),
                      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                    );
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyApp()));
              },
              child: Text("Sign in"),
            )
```

Comment: This works, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it. The other way I see this working is if the login and sign up screens are are on the same page, just separated by using a tab bar or something of that sort. That is what I had used up till now, but very clever solution by you. Thank you for that