# Firebase does not update screen after login

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-streambuilder

I'm learning flutter and trying to build an an app, but after login, firebase does not change screen, only if I use a Navigator.push. I'm using StreamBuilder and I know that have made login because the debug console says that is notifying authStateChanges, but, the screen only changes on signOut, not signIn. And now I'm using this solution [Screen does not update after SignIn in flutter/firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66033362/22667270). But I wonder if someone fixed from another way.

Here's my code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:new_project/views/auth/initialScren.dart';
import 'package:new_project/views/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
  );
  runApp(const Test());
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: null,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              textTheme: GoogleFonts.nunitoTextTheme(),
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            title: 'Rigley Test',
            home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
                stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Home();
                  } else {
                    return const InitialScreen();
                  }
                }),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, prefer_const_constructors, use_build_context_synchronously

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:new_project/base/buttons.dart';
import 'package:new_project/base/input.dart';
import '../../api_call.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  UserLogin login = UserLogin();

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool showPassword = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        minimum: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 32, 32, 8),
        child: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(height: 55),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 16),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.close_rounded),
              color: Color(0xFFC8C8C8),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          Text(
            'Digite seu email e senha para entrar',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 26,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF1D1B1E),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 28),
          Form(
            child: Column(children: [
              GhostInput(
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  validator: (email) {
                    if (email!.isEmpty ||
                        !RegExp(r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$')
                            .hasMatch(email)) {
                      return 'Insira um Email válido';
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'\s'))
                  ],
                  action: TextInputAction.next,
                  autovalidate: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  controller: emailController),
            ]),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          GhostInput(
            hintText: 'Senha',
            validator: (password) {
              if (RegExp(r'^$|^null$').hasMatch(password ?? '')) {
                return 'A senha não pode estar em branco';
              }
              return null;
            },
            obscureText: true,
            autovalidate: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            controller: passwordController,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                RegExp(r'\s'),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 24),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: PrimaryButton(
                onTap: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                  });

                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                  await login.firebaseLogin(
                    context,
                    emailController.text.trim(),
                    passwordController.text.trim(),
                  );
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
                isLoading: isLoading,
                title: 'Entrar',
                size: 50,
                color: Color(0xFF00C451),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

api_call.dart

```
ture firebaseLogin(
      BuildContext context, String userEmail, String userPassword) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: userEmail, password: userPassword);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      print(error);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            error.message.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Page changes to Home() after login.

Comment: authStateChanges "has data" even if that data is null.